# Why cannot iterate over Model.objects.all()?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In Django shell I don't have any problems in looping over `Airport.objects.all()` but in a .py I cannot iterate over my model's `QuerySet`. Here is my code:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm,DateField,ChoiceField
from flights.models import Flight,Airport
from django.forms.widgets import SelectDateWidget,TextInput
from datetime import datetime

# pylint: disable=no-member
queries=Airport.objects.all()
airports = [tuple(x) for x in queries]
```

I got `TypeError: 'Airport' object is not iterable`. Why?

Comment: the problem is nto `for x in queries`, but `tuple(x)`, `tuple(x)` expects that ou can iterate over an `Airport` *object*, and aims to wrap the elements in a tuple.

Comment: You could use `Airport.objects.values_list(flat=True)` but then you're better off just iterating over `queries`

Comment: Exactly what is `tuple(x)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
queries=Airport.objects.all()
airports = [tuple(x) for x in queries]
```

Let's break this code:

we can write this line:

```
airports = [tuple(x) for x in queries]
```

as

```
airports = []
for x in queries:
    airports.append((x))
```

queries is a query set.
x contains django queryset object for each time loop runs.
We can't directly convert django queryset object to tuple. Instead we can convert the attributes (model field names) of that object in to a tuple like this:

```
airports = [tuple(x.id) for x in queries] # [(1,), (2,)])
```

or

```
airports = [tuple(x.name) for x in queries] # [('airport1',), ('airport2',)]
```

[Django value_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) provides the same result as above:

[image]

*Note: Img source - Django documentation*